# Custom Errors Remote Only on Microsoft Azure Web App

Tags: .net, azure, azure-web-app-service

Is it possible to use `customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"` on Microsoft Azure's Web Apps?

At the moment it seems that the only way to view errors on an Web App is to set `mode="Off"`; which is not ideal as website users will see the error details.

Answer (score 0):

You can set customErrors to remoteonly, but you cannot "log in" to an Azure Web App and execute a browser to see the error.

The easiest way to get the error off of the instance is to enable [application insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-insights/).  Depending on your application, you may be able to use the [KUDU](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki) interface to execute an Invoke-WebRequest and try and see the error.  Lastly, you can always enable [remote debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio) to try and take a look at the error.